# Can raster files from ArcGIS for Desktop be visualized in Google Maps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, google-maps-api

I have raster files created using ArcGIS (Desktop application). On the other side I develop an application using google maps. Can I visualize those raster files somehow on google maps API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any kind of rasters can be visualised using Google Maps API. Please, visit:

- [Overlaying an image map type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay) and
- [Grand Canyon GeoTiff](http://www.maptiler.org/example-usgs-drg-grand-canyon-gtiff/v3.html)

If you look at the code, first, it seems to be easy to adapt it for your rasters, but you'll see it is not at all a trivial task.

You need to build the map cache tiles for each individual raster you want to display. See: [What is map caching?](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_map_caching/005300000059000000/)

I doubt that you will succeed to fulfill this task without an access to a Arcgis Server.

Once this step was completed successfully, you'll need to calculate the latitude and longitude bounds for each individual tiles, for all desired zoom levels, and to rename them accordingly.
Fortunately there is an [online tool from MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/).

Finally, all the tiles must be stored on a web server, in order to be accessed and displayed on Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert your raster file into a kml using "[layer to kml](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000004n000000)" tool in ArcGIS, then follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/)